# pytest override function thats not in a class

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

So I'm trying to understand how I can create a unit test that tests a function, which calls other functions. I want to be able to test this function, and override one of the functions that it calls because I don't want it to actually go out and make a call, I want to provide a `return_value` for that function.

So far I've seen this is mainly doable if you're using a class, but this is an API endpoint and I'm not using a class in this case. Here is the actual endpoint (simplified):

```
def _get_mock_request(self, queryStringParameters):
    return {
        "headers": {"x-api-key": "SOME-KEY"},
        "requestContext": {
            "resourceId": "t89kib",
            "authorizer": {
                "x-authorizer-key": "SOME KEY",
                "principalId": "9de3f415a97e410386dbef146e88744e",
                "integrationLatency": 572,
            },
        },
        "pathParameters": {"proxy": "unittest"},
        "resource": "/{proxy }",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "queryStringParameters": queryStringParameters,
        "body": None,
    }


def get(request, response):
    """ApiGateway GET function"""
    if validator.valid_raw_data_request(request, response):
        handle_query(request, response)
    return response
```

So what I am trying to do, is simply just override the `handle_query` function, and tell it what return value I want. Here is what I've currently tried (and many different variations/flavors of this):

```
@mock.patch('requests.get', side_effect=mock_response.requests_get)
@mock.patch('application.v1.logic.common.raw_data_request_handler.handle_query')
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'DEFAULT_ATHENA_MAX_RESULTS': '100'})
def test_get_pass(self, mock_handle_query, mock_get):
    mock_handle_query.return_value = raw_fields_json_mock
```

Except I still see this function being called, and then also going out and making API requests which I don't want. I know this is definitely something I'm not quite understanding about Pytest (fairly new to Python in general, came from Node). But I just don't know **what** im missing here. Based on everything I've googled, this **should** work.

Comment: You are using `mock_get` as parameter - is this a fixture, or didn't you show another decorator? Also, `full_path_to_this_file` points to the module where `get` is defined, right?

Comment: no i also want to mock a get request, so I am doing that too (for my api, not the one my get is calling). The full path to this file is the file of the FUNCTION that my get request (as shown above) is calling, if that makes any sense?

Comment: We have a custom request object that we pass to our endpoints, which is why im using mock_get as well. I will add code to make it make more sense.

Comment: You may use the wrong patch path then, check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6), unless `raw_data_request_handler` _is_ the module where `get` is defined.